# Email Form Submits successfully but I do not get the phone number field in the record

Tags: php, forms, email

I am using a custom optin page with a form , While testing and in work,When I submit the form I get all the details on my email except the phone number , I do not see any problem with the codes , I tried diff things like changing the value and stuff but it did not work, Here is the form code

```
<div class="form fix ">
                    <p class="form-text">Fill This Out and See Your <br>Timeshare Report</p>
                    <form name="contactform" action="mail-script.php" method="POST">
                        <label for="fname">First Name:
                            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="lname">Last Name:
                            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="email">Email Address:
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="phone">Phone Number:
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="phone">Alternate Phone:
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="aphone" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="resort">Resort Name:
                            <input type="text" name="resort" id="resort" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="amount">Amount Owed? $:
                            <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" />
                            <p style="font-size: 12px !important;margin-top: -14px;padding-right: 30px;text-align:right;">
                            If Paid Off Leave Zero, Else Put Amount</p>
                        </label><br>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <div class="check-text fix">
                                <p>I'm Considering To</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="check-one fix">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="sell"/> Sell It <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="buy"/> Buy It <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="rent "/> Rent  It 
                            </div>
                            <div class="check-two fix">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="cancel"/> Cancel Mortgage <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="ownership"/> End Ownership <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="give"/> Give It Back
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                                 <p class="captcha">
                            <img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' ><br>
                            <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label><br>
                            <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text"><br>
                            <small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small>
                        </p>
                        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="" />
                        <p class="submit-text">Ensure all fields are completed and correct, allowing you more benefits, while preventing abuse of our data.</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the mail script which sends me the email

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */

$myemail  = "**MYEMAIL**";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$fname    = check_input($_POST['fname'], "Enter your first name");
$lname    = check_input($_POST['lname'], "Enter your last name");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$phone    = check_input($_POST['phone']);
$resort   = check_input($_POST['resort']);
$amount   = check_input($_POST['amount']);
$call     = check_input($_POST['call']);

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:


First Name : $fname
Last Name : $lname
E-mail: $email
Phone : $phone
Resort: $resort
Amount: $amount
Call  : $call

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: index.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
if (strtolower($_POST['code']) != 'mycode') {die('Wrong access code');}
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Here is the online url of the page
http://timesharesgroup.com/sell/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two form elements with the same name. The second one overwrites the first one and you never receive it. You also forget your alternate phone number in your PHP code.

```
<label for="phone">Phone Number:
     <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
</label><br>
<label for="phone">Alternate Phone:
     <input type="text" name="altphone" id="aphone" />
</label><br>
```

Your PHP:

```
$phone    = check_input($_POST['phone']);
$altphone = check_input($_POST['altphone']);

Phone : $phone
Alt Phone : $altphone
Resort: $resort
```

Comment: Thanks Alot for Your quickest response , it worked , I am really grateful

Answer (score 3):

Your alternative phone number is overwriting your phone number:

```
       <label for="phone">Phone Number:
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
       </label><br>
       <label for="phone">Alternate Phone:
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="aphone" />
                                   ^^^^^ here
       </label><br>
```

Changing the name for the alternative number should fix that.

Comment: Thanks Alot for Your quickest response